# Why doesn't the Static Method Value Reader resolve my method in Data Exchange Framework?

Tags: data-exchange-framework

Sitecore 9.0.2, DEF 2.0.1

I have a basic Static Method Value Reader set up:

[image: Static Method Value Reader configuration in Sitecore]

It is supposed to call the configured method here:

```
namespace Custom.Sc.DataExchange.Framework.ValueReaders
{
    public static class StaticMethods
    {
        public static string ReturnEmptyStringIfNull(object[] arguments)
        {
            if (arguments.Length <= 0)
                return string.Empty;

            string input = arguments[0].ToString();

            return input.Equals("NULL", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? string.Empty : input;
        }
    }
}
```

But my static method code is never executed. Why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues:

1. The **Type With Static Method** field needs an [assembly-qualified name](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname) (e.g. `Custom.Sc.DataExchange.Framework.ValueReaders.StaticMethods, Custom.Sc.DataExchange`)
2. The method in **Method Name** must accept the same parameter type as is coming from your source in the mapping (e.g. `string`):

   ```
   public static string ReturnEmptyStringIfNull(string rawValue)
   {
       if (rawValue == null)
           return null;

       return rawValue.Equals("NULL", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? string.Empty : rawValue;
   }
   ```